# DbManager Yii2 unserialize when deploy in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, yii2

I got this error when I upload yii2 app into ubuntu server.
In my local using windows 10 is no problem.

I use PHP7 and Apache2,

```
Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 24 bytes
    [file] => /var/www/html/yii_tresnamuda/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rbac/DbManager.php
    [line] => 439
)
```

in my config/web.php

```
 'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // only support DbManager
    ],
    'redis' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting refers to invalid serialized data due to invalid length, and something to do with `rbac`. More specifically, it seems that the problem is in some row of your `auth_rule`, in the `data` column. Go there, check all the serialized data and, if needed, recalculate lengths. If that it too much, I would delete the rules and recreate them manually again (I would go one by one until the error disappears).